# CSS <HR> With Ornament

Tags: html, css

I have been struggling with something which in theory should be very simple for a few days now... and i am determined not to give up.

I am trying to achieve this:

[image]

Essentially horizontal rule, with an ornament between - the HR will span the full width of the screen.

So i sliced my PSD to drop out the ornament as a image - and i am trying to overlay this onto a

---

centered but failing miserably.

My Markup:

```
<div>
  <hr>
  <img src='assets/img/ornament.png' class='center'>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
hr{

height: 2px;
color: #578daf;
background-color: #578daf;
border:0;
```

}

I just cant figure out how to make the image appear in the centre of the HR.... Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: @CaseyRobinson not sure i understand?

Comment: Your markups are html4.01  ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the markup tp

```
<div class='hr'>
  <hr>
  <img src='assets/img/ornament.png' alt=''>
</div>
```

Add the following to the stylesheet, replacing 16px by a suitable value that depends on the height of the image and the expected font size.

```
.hr {  text-align: center; }
.hr img { position: relative; top: -16px; }
```

However, a better approach is to use just an image, centered inside a `div` element that has a suitable background image that repeats horizontally. The background image would be a piece that is of the same color as the overall page background but has a horizontal line in the middle.

Answer (score 16):

You can also accomplish this with a CSS pseudo element. All that's needed for HTML is the  `<hr>`

```
hr:after { 
    background: url('yourimagehere.png') no-repeat top center;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 30px; /* height of the ornament */
    position: relative;
    top: -15px; /* half the height of the ornament */
}
```

Comment: This solution avoids from using extra markups and fully working.

Comment: I think this is the cleanest method for the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9EFdF/). You can set the ornament image as a background on the `div` with the `ornament` class.

Comment: I tried this out but changing the code in the fiddle to use backgound: url(''); made the image disapper...

Answer (score 2):

off the cuff...
using the center image for the hr and a repeated line segment for the div...

```
    <style>
      .line hr {height: 16px; background: url(as_image.jpg) center center no-repeat;border:0;}
      .line {background: url(as_line.jpg) center repeat-x;}
    </style>

    <div class="line"><hr></div>
```